# Calculate font size based on size of display area

Tags: .net, vb.net, font-size

I know that I can calculate the display area for a given font using

`TextRenderer.MeasureText("Text", New Font(Arial, 12.0F)`

I want to calculate the size of a font I should be using in order to fit a given display area.    Is there a function that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I know no, there's no any function to do that.
I used a function that, changing font size from a lower value to upper ones, checked which font size was the one I needed.
For example you can start from 8f and increase it with 1f; remember anyway that not any size is good for any font, so you can have some "distortion".